# How can I transfer the selected text and value of one select box to another with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If I have two selects like this?

```
<select id="A">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="B">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How can I transfer the selected value and text from select A  to select B.  I don't want this to happen in response to any change or click.  I just need some way that I can at a later time sync what appears in the select B window to what's in select A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your two `select`s are same then:

You can simply try this:

```
  $('#B').val( $('#A').val() );
```

You can make it through a function call also:

```
function changeValue() {
  $('#B').val( $('#A').val() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var selA = $('#A option:selected').val();
  $('#B option[value="'+ selA +'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

See [demo](http://jsbin.com/avixeh/1) (click change after changing first select)

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```
var idx = $('#A option:selected').index();

$('#B option').eq(idx).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

What if both list are different

```
var _AOption = $('#A option:selected');
var _BOptions = $('#B option');
var isInList = 0;
_BOptions.each(function()
{
    $(this).removeAttr('selected');
    if($(this).attr('value') == _AOption.attr('value'))
    {
        $(this).attr('selected', '1');
        isInList = 1;
    }
});

if(isInList  == 0)
{
    $('#B').append('<option selected="1" value="'+_AOption.attr('value')+'" >'+_AOption.html()+'</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `append()` method:

```
$('#B').append($('#A option:selected'))
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dT6Fa/)